# What is the aspect of Javascript and DOM scoping and assignment rules which prevent the code from working on the second block of html?

Tags: javascript, variables, dom

The html code is below is exported form orgmode and the Javascript function is meant to transform the `<pre class="src src-emacs-lisp">` block to `<pre><code class="lisp">` for it to be syntax-highlighted by [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org).

For some Javascript quirk I don't understand the function doesn't work on the second block. I thought it was the syntax of the html code in it, but when I rearrange the blocks, the fault always happens on the second. There must be something about the scoping rules of Javascript that I don't understand. The code to locate the blocks works fine and if I print them out without processing it works they all show up. It is when I apply the transformations that things go wrong. What feature of Javascript am I not comprehending?

The code which just prints them out works fine. They are all detected.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
var lispBlocks = document.getElementsByClassName('src src-emacs-lisp');
alert(lispBlocks.length);
for (i=0;i<lispBlocks.length;i++){
    var iHtml = lispBlocks[i].outerHTML;
    //alert(lispBlocks[i].outerHTML);
    alert(iHtml);
  };
});
```

With the code that transforms them, things go south

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
var lispBlocks = document.getElementsByClassName('src src-emacs-lisp');
alert(lispBlocks.length);
var iHtml;
var lBlockText;
for (i=0;i<lispBlocks.length;i++){
    //lispBlocks[i].className = '';
    iHtml = lispBlocks[i].innerHTML;
    alert(lispBlocks[i].innerHTML);
    alert(lispBlocks[i].outerHTML);
    lBlockText = '<pre><code class="lisp">' + iHtml + '</code></pre>';
    alert(lBlockText);
    lispBlocks[i].outerHTML = lBlockText;
    //alert(lispBlocks[i].outerHTML);
    //hljs.highlightBlock(lispBlocks[i]);
  };
});


<!-- language: lang-html -->

<div class="org-src-container">
<pre class="src src-emacs-lisp">;; after splitting a frame automatically, switch to the new window (unless we
;; were in the minibuffer)
(setq split-window-preferred-function 'my/split-window-func)
(defun my/split-window-func (&amp;optional window)
(let ((new-window (split-window-sensibly window)))
    (if (not (active-minibuffer-window))
    (select-window new-window))))
</pre>
</div>


<div class="org-src-container">
<pre class="src src-emacs-lisp"> (defun split-window--select-window (orig-func &amp;rest args)
"Switch to the other window after a `split-window'"
(let ((cur-window (selected-window))
      (new-window (apply orig-func args)))
  (when (equal (window-buffer cur-window) (window-buffer new-window))
    (select-window new-window))
  new-window))
  (advice-add &#39;split-window :around #&#39;split-window--select-window)
</pre>
</div>

<div class="org-src-container">
<pre class="src src-emacs-lisp">;; settings for default frames
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . FONT ))
;;or

;; set-face-atribute, ='default nil= for all existing frames and new frames
;; ='default t= for new frames only
;; function sets a number of attributes besides :font see docs
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font FONT )

;;set frame font
(set-frame-font FONT nil t)
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: `function doesn't work` obviously, otherwise you wouldn't be here - could you describe what happens vs what you expect, and any errors in the browser developer tools that you may be getting

Comment: the function works on the first and third blocks, but not the second. The detection works correctly on all the 3 blocks. The transformation fails to work on the second.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out as soon as I looked at the code again - the skipping every second block is classic example of changing  elements in a "live" list - see answer for two possible solutions

Comment: Thanks. Where can I get more help on the **live** category of selections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getElementsByClassName` returns a **live** list

Therefore, when changing the **outerHTML** you change the list, because you've changed the class of the element that is in the live list

In the example, you'd have a list of elements, `[a, b, c]`, and `i == 0`

You change `a` such that it disappears from the list, now the list is `[b, c]` but `i` increments to 1, so the next iteration changes `c`, skipping b

use

```
var lispBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.src.src-emacs-lisp');
```

instead

Alternatively you could use a while loop

```
while(lispBlocks.length) {
    iHtml = lispBlocks[0].innerHTML; // note, the hard coded `0` here
    // etc
}
```